# Okay for ivar to store reference to owner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view controller that needs one of its ivars to call a method on it at some point. Is it acceptable for the ivar to store a reference to its owner? Could this cause any problems? If so, better way?

```
// From MainViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyObject *myObject;

@end

// From MyObject.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id myOwner;

@end
```

Comment: can't you do this using the `delegate` paradigm?

Comment: all the ways I think there should be no problems with this, but the property `myOwner` should be `weak` not `strong` as the relation between objects is not of ownership

Comment: @tkanzakic hmm.. Good point about delegation. But would delegation be desirable for such small applications (eg. only has one delegate method)?

Comment: if you wish to avoid this circular reference I think it could be a good choice, I see no problem to declare a delegate with just one method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When 2 objects have strong references to each other that will create retain loop - so they will never get deallocated (and so you will get memory leak) unless you manually break the loop (e.g. set myObject property to nil on viewWillDisappear if appropriate).

Much better way will be that "child" object will have weak reference to its "owner" so you won't have retain loop at all:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id myOwner;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you want to think about changing the property declaration to:

```
@property ( weak, nonatomic ) id myOwner;
```

This way you avoid a possible [retain cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447).

Answer (score 0):

a block could do the trick too.